# observableArray is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am working in a client development environment and have to adhere to their coding standards. I have the following JS and HTML. My observableArray is coming as not defined. I am not able to get it working. Even the console.logs are printing the correct values.

Please don't worry about `ko.applyBindings`. It is taken care of.

My JS Code:

```
define(
    ['knockout'],
    function (ko) {
        "use strict";
        return {
            onLoad: function (widget) {
                widget.getDetails= function (prod) {
                    var abc = prod.DetailsNumbers();
                    console.log(abc);
                    var someArray= [];
                    someArray= abc.split(',');
                    //console.log(someArray);
                    var anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray();

                    for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
                        var temp = {
                            "prodName": ko.observable(someArray[i])
                        };
                        anotherObservableArray.push(temp);
                    }
                    console.log(anotherObservableArray());
                };
            }
        }
    }
);
```

My HTML Code:

```
<div id="someId">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Button Here</td>
                <td><button data-bind="click: getDetails(product())">Click me</button></td> 
            </tr>// this here is working fine
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: anotherObservableArray"> // this doesnt work
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: prodName"> </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> anotherObservableArray is not defined

Comment: @user3297291, it has been taken care of. Added that to the question as well.

Comment: I noticed you added it, so I removed my comment. Your question does not really make clear what the binding context of the HTML is. `getDetails` creates an observable array named `anotherObservableArray`, but it only exists within the scope of the method.

Comment: @user3297291 how can I make it a global scoped array?

Comment: Does your click handler already work? If it does, that means your current binding context is `widget`. If you want to make it global, it has to be in the view model you're using inside `applyBindings`. You can then access it via `$root.anotherObservableArray` inside your `foreach` binding. You'll also have to rewrite your `getDetails` method. Maybe read some more about MVVM and knockout's best practices. Does that help?

Comment: yes the click handler works fine. how can I modify the code to make it global scoped? an examples or something you show?

Comment: There's not enough code for me to answer your question. I can't see how your `getDetails` click binding would work (since it already calls the method instead of referencing it). Please provide a fiddle or a more complete picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't expose `anotherObservableArray` outside the function scope you declare it in. Basically your code is of this format:

```
{
  onLoad: function (widget) {
    widget.getDetails = function (prod) {
      var anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray();
      // push some items into the array
      console.log(anotherObservableArray());
    };
  }
}
```

You somehow need to expose the `anotherObservableArray` outside the function. For example:

```
{
  onLoad: function (widget) {
    widget.getDetails = function (prod) {
      var anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray();
      // push some items into the array
      console.log(anotherObservableArray());
      this.anotherObservableArray = anotherObservableArray; // Expose it on the function
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: that fixed the issue...however I am facing a new issue. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434173/observablearray-not-updating-the-ui

Answer (score 1):

Move `var anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray();` to your VM definition and ensure it's exposed (i.e. "public"). I am imagining you do have something like this:

```
var vm = {
    // ...
    // most likely you are exposing getDetails() already 
    // .... 

    anotherObservableArray: ko.observableArray()
};

// ...

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```