# observableArray not updating the UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am facing a problem that the UI only updates with correct data after a refresh of the page. I am coming from here [observableArray is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430705/observablearray-is-not-defined)

My JS Code:

```
define(
    ['knockout'],
    function (ko) {
        "use strict";
        return {
            onLoad: function (widget) {
                widget.getDetails= function (prod) {
                    var abc = prod.DetailsNumbers();
                    console.log(abc);
                    var someArray= [];
                    someArray= abc.split(',');
                    //console.log(someArray);
                    widget.anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray();

                    for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
                        var temp = {
                            "prodName": ko.observable(someArray[i])
                        };
                        var myKoObservableArray = widget.anotherObservableArray;
                        myKoObservableArray.push(temp);

                    }
                    console.log(myKoObservableArray());
                    this.myKoObservableArray = myKoObservableArray;
                };
            }
        }
    }
);
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="someId">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Button Here</td>
                <td><button data-bind="click: getDetails(product())">Click me</button></td> 
            </tr>// this here is working fine
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: myKoObservableArray">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: prodName"> </span> //this changes only after a refresh
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The `data-bind="text: prodName"` changes value only after a refresh of the page.

Comment: can you please create a fiddle for the same..

Comment: Second that, except that the question itself needs the code. See [mcve] for guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Create the array *once* in onLoad, and then just update it.  Don't keep creating it each time.

```
define(
    ['knockout'],
    function (ko) {
        "use strict";
        return {
            onLoad: function (widget) {
                widget.myKoObservableArray = ko.observableArray();
                widget.getDetails= function (prod) {
                    var abc = prod.DetailsNumbers();
                    console.log(abc);
                    var someArray= [];
                    someArray= abc.split(',');
                    //console.log(someArray);

                    // empty the array
                    widget.myKoObservableArray([]);

                    for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
                        var temp = {
                            "prodName": ko.observable(someArray[i])
                        };
                        widget.myKoObservableArray.push(temp);

                    }
                    console.log(widget.myKoObservableArray());
                };
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: that didnt seem to work. also, i am getting duplicate array values now.

Comment: yeah I forgot to actually empty the array instead of just commenting that it needed to be emptied. :)  As for why it still doesn't work: I'm not sure what you are using and when `onLoad` gets called.  Perhaps the html has already been bound before then and thus your `myKoObservableArray` did not yet exist.